# Grouping dates to nearest

Tags: javascript, momentjs

`moment.js` and  `loadash.js`

```
const startTime =  [ '2021-09-30T02:38:56', '2021-09-30T02:39:56', '2021-09-30T02:40:56', '2021-09-30T02:10:56', '2021-09-30T02:11:56' ]
```

First 3 dates are same with 1 minute difference, second two dates are same with 1 minute difference.

I wanted to group the dates which are just  5 minutes difference, like below.

```
[ 
 [ 2021-09-30T02:38:56', '2021-09-30T02:39:56', '2021-09-30T02:40:56' ], 
 [ '2021-09-30T02:10:56', '2021-09-30T02:11:56' ]    
]
```

I able to achieve the result with multiple array iterations, but is there any pretty way?

Comment: You will need a base. *"5 minutes difference"* relative to what? cannot be to each-other. if you will have 100 dates, each is 4 minutes after the one before it, then they are all *"5 minutes difference"*... you need to first decide what is the "anchor" here.

Comment: You will need a very smart algorithm which finds the largest group which can be created that has the minimum difference between the values. This is more of a mathematical problem than programmatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion with a single array iteration if that is pretty way for you:

```js
const startTime = ['2021-09-30T02:38:56', '2021-09-30T02:39:56', '2021-09-30T02:40:56', '2021-09-30T02:10:56', '2021-09-30T02:11:56'];
axisSTime = moment(startTime[1]);
const groupedSTimes = [];
let groupedSTime = [startTime[1]];
const MAX_DIFF_MIN = 5;
startTime.slice(1).forEach((sTime, i, slicedArray) => {
  const diffMin = Math.abs(moment(sTime).diff(axisSTime) / 60000);
  if (diffMin > MAX_DIFF_MIN) {
    groupedSTimes.push(groupedSTime);
    groupedSTime = [];
    axisSTime = moment(sTime);
  }
  groupedSTime.push(sTime);
  if(i == slicedArray.length - 1) {
    groupedSTimes.push(groupedSTime);
  }
});
console.log(groupedSTimes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```